# No push token given for ios using pushwoosh

Tags: ios, marmalade, pushwoosh

I am trying to add pushwoosh through marmalade to mobile application (at the moment on ios device). Like on 
http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/marmalade-push-sdk-integration/

I have add to Info.plist

```
<key>Pushwoosh_APPID</key>
<string>1****-A****</string>
```

(I create app on pushwoosh site adn copy code to Info.plist but I didn't configure anything for ios on site, there is nothing about that in tutrial)
But when I start application I get info

```
Response "200 no error": string: {"status_code":210,"status_message":"No push token given","response":null}
```

It enters ad OnRegistered callback but token is empty. Does anyone what is wrong ?
( I done like on tutorial link, there is no need to do anything with certificate in tutorial)

Comment: I looks like you did not change 'Pushwoosh_APPID' to the app id that you registered on the site. Change that, it should be the name you named the project on the site.

Answer (score 0):

The provision profile you use must have push notifications enabled on that. You need to edit the mobilepovision from the Apple developer portal and add push notification.

Comment: And also look for "Push notification will not be delivered" warning in Deploy tool log, while making the ipa

Answer (score 0):

> "Blockquote I done like on tutorial link, there is no need to do anything with certificate in tutorial"

Have you configured Pushwoosh for your application according to Pushwoosh [iOS configuration guide](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/iphone-configuration-guide/)?